# how to create a patch action with backpack for laravel

Tags: laravel-backpack

Hello every body i am new with both laravel and backpack , so i read the documentation [backpack documentation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/) , so i want to create a line action(action that apears in every entry) that change an attribut which is by the way a 1-n relation (assign action that assign an entity to a user). can somme one helps me, or just give me the best path to follow .

```
public function assign()
{
    return view("welcome");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Backpack v4 you should probably take a look at [creating custom operations](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/crud-operations#creating-a-custom-operation).

[This example](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/crud-operations#creating-a-new-operation-with-an-interface) should be helpful to you. It shows how to create an Operation that includes a button on the line stack, and separate page for that operation.

Hope it helps.